# getElementById returning null when trying to build Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, getelementbyid

I'm trying to build a chrome extension which allows you to play an mp3 file (pre-selected) by clicking a button- very simple for now I know! However, when I am trying to access the button in my js file my function only returns null. I have moved the script tag to the end of my body and included a 'DOMContentLoaded' event listener, as shown below, but I still can't shake this error- and this is after trying to incorporate practically every suggestion I've found on other similar questions! Any help greatly appreciated. 
[my javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0V2s.png)

[my html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vPeP.png) 
I should note I ran this code through another IDE (the one provided by the CS50x course) and everything worked fine.

Comment: If you look at the error list on chrome://extensions page, it shows all old items forever until you manually clear the list by clicking the button there. To debug the popup properly though you can simply right-click inside the popup and then select "inspect".

Comment: Please don't post code as an image but rather as a text.